# splitting sun tunnel

Tags: solar

We have a nice sun tunnel in the kitchen soffited area that I would like to split off with a 90 t and add a 4' extension and an additional plate on a vertcial side of the soffit. I realize I am not going to get as much light as another unit but with the multiple roofing levels branching the existing tunnel sounds very attractive. Does anyone make a fitting or am I on my own to fabricate such a piece to attach my extension? Has anyone tried this?

Comment: If you attempt this use a Y rather than a T, as that may split the light better.

Answer (score 1):

The longer and less direct the run,the more light you will lose to absorption. And of course the split would mean you lose light in the original location.

If you really want to do this anyway, I'd consider real optics -- half-silvered mirror, focusing lenses, front-surface mirror at far end -- but cost would be high.

A second sun-tube/skylight seems a better bet. Or solar panel driving (a) full-spectrum bulb(s), though I agree that isn't the same thing.